# Trying to make fixed table headers with horizontal scroll bar. How to set overflow: auto, but keep margins transparent?

Tags: javascript, css, html, optimization

I am trying to make a table with fixed headers and horizontal scrolling functionality, but to do so I need to make the "section"'s top margin transparent in what I have here:

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
.section {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding-top: 37px;
    background: #500;
    margin-top: 37px;
}

.container {
    margin-top: -37px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 200px;
}
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    width:100%;
}
td + td {
    border-left:1px solid #eee;
}
td, th {
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
    background: #ddd;
    color: #000;
    padding: 10px 25px;
}
th {
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    color: transparent;
    border: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
th div {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:-37px;
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 9px 25px;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: -25px;
    line-height: normal;
    border-left: 1px solid #800;
}
th:first-child div {
    border: none;
}

<div class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr class="header">
                    <th>Table attribute name
                        <div>Table attribute name</div>
                    </th>
                    <th>Value
                        <div>Value</div>
                    </th>
                    <th>Description
                        <div>Description</div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>align</td>
                    <td>left, center, right</td>
                    <td>Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01. Specifies the alignment of a table according to surrounding text</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>bgcolor</td>
                    <td>rgb(x,x,x), #xxxxxx, colorname</td>
                    <td>Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01. Specifies the background color for a table</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>border</td>
                    <td>1,""</td>
                    <td>Specifies whether the table cells should have borders or not</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>cellpadding</td>
                    <td>pixels</td>
                    <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between the cell wall and the cell content</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>cellspacing</td>
                    <td>pixels</td>
                    <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between cells</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>frame</td>
                    <td>void, above, below, hsides, lhs, rhs, vsides, box, border</td>
                    <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the outside borders that should be visible</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>rules</td>
                    <td>none, groups, rows, cols, all</td>
                    <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the inside borders that should be visible</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>summary</td>
                    <td>text</td>
                    <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies a summary of the content of a table</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>width</td>
                    <td>pixels, %</td>
                    <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the width of a table</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/byB9d/6212/

Thanks in advance to anyone with suggestions!

P.S. I would like a pure css solution, please!

Comment: I don't understand *"visible in a transparent margin"*... a margin is a visual space, so how can it not be transparent, and how can something be "in" it? are you looking for `padding-top`?

Comment: ....Or.....css `margin`....

Comment: I want to be able to see the content that is being hidden by overflow: auto in the margin

Comment: I just made a pretty huge edit to the question.. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to remove most of your css to (hopefully) give a clearer answer to this question. I did however not change any of your html.

[Fiddle with code](https://jsfiddle.net/v6m2nw9o/1/)

**x-scrolling and width**

This method relies on using the "table" as a container for "thead" and "tbody". "table" will determine the scrolling along the x-axis. Therefore it has "overflow-x: auto". This way the "thead" can stay positioned above the "tbody" while scrolling the table. (will be explained later)

This element also determines the width the table will take up on your webpage.

In order for the content to scroll horizontally we have to make sure the total width of "tbody" and "thead" is longer than the width of "table".

Finally you should also add the same width to your cells so the headers appear properly above your data. I did this by applying a width to "tr th:nth-child(1), tr td:nth-child(1)" (for each column).

**y-scrolling and height**

We want the "thead" to stay positioned on top of our table. Even when we scroll. Therefore we simply convert it to a block element.

The "tbody" is another story. we want to be able to vertically scroll it. Therefore we add "overflow-y: auto" and also set a fixed height for the element (otherwise it will just drop down and not scroll).

The total height of the table will be the height of "thead" and "tbody". The "table will adapt its size to fit it."

**The CSS (html is the same as it is in the question post)**

```
td, th {
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
    background: #ddd;
    color: #000;
    padding: 10px 25px;
}

th div{display: none;} /*why is this html even here!?!?*/

table {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;   
    width: 75%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
thead{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 700px; /*total width of columns*/
}
tbody{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 700px; /*total width of columns.*/
}
tr th:nth-child(1), tr td:nth-child(1){
    width: 100px;
}
tr th:nth-child(2), tr td:nth-child(2){
    width: 150px;
}
tr th:nth-child(3), tr td:nth-child(3){
    width: 450px;
}
```

*PS: I assume this is what you were trying to ask.*

Comment: Yes, this is about as far as I could get it with this approach.. The only problem here is that the vertical scroll bar isn't visible unless you scroll all the way to the right. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I don t think it's possible without also creating a scrollbar for "thead" with only CSS. Maybe write some javascript code that horizontally moves "thead" when you horizontally scroll "tbody"? Then use "tbody" for scrolling (both horizontally and vertically).

Comment: Yea, that's what I figured.. Thanks for your help, though!